# SphinxQL MATCH - how to use?

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

Explain to me please, what's the MATCH() operator in SphinxQL - how to use it?

Sorry if my question is stupid for somebody, but I really couldn't find any normal explanation in the Web of this.

For example, I have this request:

```
SELECT tid FROM message WHERE MATCH('test');
```

What does it mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its quite literally the 'workhorse' of sphinx. The query you want to 'search' the index with. Pretty much the point of Sphinx is to run 'full-text queryies'

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-select